# Compare Two Eval values in a conditional operator in Repeater c#

Tags: c#, repeater

I tried:

```
<option value="<%# Eval("DataID")%>" selected="(<%# Eval("NewID")%>==<%# Eval("DataID")%>)?'selected':''"> <%# Eval("ColorName")%></option>
```

but output i am getting(inspect element)

```
<option value="13047" selected="(13050==13047)?'selected':''"> ..BLACK</option>

<option value="13048" selected="(13050==13048)?'selected':''"> .CHARCOAL</option>

<option value="13049" selected="(13050==13049)?'selected':''"> BANANA</option>
```

Is there any other way to use conditional operator or If condition in Repeater

Comment: There is a syntax error in the code above: *<option value="<%# Eval("DataID")%>"* double quotes are being used **twice**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
selected='<%# Eval("NewID").ToString() == Eval("DataID").ToString() ?  "selected" : "" %>'
```

**EDIT:**

Well, my html is a bit rusty :=) Although the above code is syntactically correct it will not produce the desired result, i.e. to get the specified `option` selected. Sth like this is most probably what the OP wants to achieve:

```
<option value='<%# Eval("DataID")%>' '<%# Eval("NewID").ToString() == Eval("DataID").ToString() ?  "selected" : "" %>'>
```

Comment: @A R Sekhar Well, comparison might have failed, but a syntax error is probably due to copy/paste error. Try performing a ToString() after applying Eval. See my edited answer.

Comment: I tried the way @Giorgos specified but throwing error as syntax error and Expression Expected

Comment: @A R Sekhar I have tested the code in my answer and it works ok. Have you corrected the syntax error in the OP?

Answer (score 0):

try in this way

```
selected='<%= Eval("NewID")==Eval("DataID")) ? String.Format("{0}","selected") : String.Empty %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML scriplet, you need to be consistent about single quote and double quotes.

Basically you need to execute:

```
    Eval("NewID") == Eval("DataID") ? "Your True Value" : "Your False Value"
```

So, decorate about statement with the scriplet and ' - single quote

```
    '<%# Eval("NewID") == Eval("DataID") ? "Your True Value" : "Your False Value" %>'
```

For the syntax of Eval() in HTML(aspx) pages:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe(v=vs.110).aspx