# ASP.NET in line string comparison

Tags: asp.net

I've inherited some code that displays a list of calendar events with a start date and end date.  The values come from a SQL db through a stored procedure, eventually making their way onto an aspx page.

If an event starts and ends on the same day I don't want to display the end date.  Despite having visually compared the data, my attempt to implement this using the inline snippet below has failed and it continues to show EndDate:

```
<%# (Eval("EDate") == Eval("SDate")) ? "BLANK" : "EndDate" %>
```

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong?
Or how I could implement this on the Stored Procedure side? The code generating this there is:

```
    SDate =
        CASE 
           WHEN STR(DAY(startdate)) = 1 THEN DATENAME(mm, [StartDate])+' '+LTRIM(STR(DAY(startdate)))+ 'st' + ', ' 
           WHEN STR(DAY(startdate)) =2 THEN DATENAME(mm, [StartDate])+ ' ' +LTRIM(STR(DAY(startdate)))  + 'nd' + ', ' 
           WHEN STR(DAY(startdate)) =3 THEN DATENAME(mm, [StartDate])+ ' ' +LTRIM(STR(DAY(startdate))) + 'rd'+ ', '
           WHEN STR(DAY(startdate)) =21 THEN DATENAME(mm, [StartDate])+ ' ' + LTRIM(STR(DAY(startdate)))  + 'st' + ', ' 
           WHEN STR(DAY(startdate)) =22 THEN DATENAME(mm, [StartDate])+ ' ' +LTRIM(STR(DAY(startdate)))  + 'nd' + ', ' 
           WHEN STR(DAY(startdate)) =23 THEN DATENAME(mm, [StartDate])+ ' ' + LTRIM(STR(DAY(startdate)))+ 'rd'+ ', ' 
           WHEN STR(DAY(startdate)) =31 THEN DATENAME(mm, [StartDate])+ ' ' +LTRIM(STR(DAY(startdate)))  + 'st' + ', '
     ELSE DATENAME(mm, [StartDate])+ ' ' +LTRIM(STR(DAY(startdate)))+ 'th'+ ', ' 
       end,

    EDate =
    CASE 
       WHEN STR(DAY(ENDdate)) = 1 THEN DATENAME(mm, [ENDdate])+' '+LTRIM(STR(DAY(ENDdate)))+ 'st' + ', '
       WHEN STR(DAY(ENDdate)) =2 THEN DATENAME(mm, [ENDdate])+ ' ' +LTRIM(STR(DAY(ENDdate)))  + 'nd' + ', '
       WHEN STR(DAY(ENDdate)) =3 THEN DATENAME(mm, [ENDdate])+ ' ' +LTRIM(STR(DAY(ENDdate))) + 'rd'+ ', '
       WHEN STR(DAY(ENDdate)) =21 THEN DATENAME(mm, [ENDdate])+ ' ' + LTRIM(STR(DAY(ENDdate)))  + 'st' + ', '
       WHEN STR(DAY(ENDdate)) =22 THEN DATENAME(mm, [ENDdate])+ ' ' +LTRIM(STR(DAY(ENDdate)))  + 'nd' + ', '
       WHEN STR(DAY(ENDdate)) =23 THEN DATENAME(mm, [ENDdate])+ ' ' + LTRIM(STR(DAY(ENDdate)))+ 'rd'+ ', '
       WHEN STR(DAY(ENDdate)) =31 THEN DATENAME(mm, [ENDdate])+ ' ' +LTRIM(STR(DAY(ENDdate)))  + 'st' + ', '
 ELSE DATENAME(mm, [ENDdate])+ ' ' +LTRIM(STR(DAY(ENDdate)))+ 'th'+ ', '
   end
```

Comment: You can try with `Eval("EDate").ToString() == Eval("SDate").ToString()`, as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27693624/compare-two-eval-values-in-a-conditional-operator-in-repeater-c-sharp.

Comment: Thanks ConnorsFan - that did the trick!